# Unable to access site using https

Tags: ssl, nginx

I'm currently serving the server using nginx with the following configuration.

```
server {
    server_name www.skipven.xyz skipven.xyz;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/ari-bot/aribot;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/ari-bot/ari-bot.sock;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/skipven.xyz/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/skipven.xyz/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = www.skipven.xyz) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = skipven.xyz) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    server_name www.skipven.xyz skipven.xyz;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

When I try to access `http://skipven.xyz`, It's successfully redirected to `https://skipven.xyz`  . But `https://skipven.xyz` doesn't return anything. I also can't find any access log of the https request but http request is logged like charm.

Other things to note:

Running `sudo nginx -t` return the following response:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Running `sudo ufw status` return the following response:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: What you are getting in error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure that your web application is running, try to curl to unix socket. If it still does not work, which cloud service do you use right now? If you use aws or gce, you still need to configure their firewall.

Comment: Just realized I haven't update my aws firewall setting, thanks